# Ruby Pb. with "STDIN.getc" and "case when" in a loop

Tags: ruby

I have some problems with the following code :

```
puts "Press a key"
key = STDIN.getc
puts key.class
puts "You have pressed #{key}"
puts key.class
while key != "f" do
    case key
    when "g"
      puts "It's 'g'"
    when "h"
      puts "It's 'h'"
    when "j"
      puts "It's 'j'"
    else
      puts "You gave me #{key} -- I have no idea what to do with that."
    end
    puts "Press a key"
    key = STDIN.getc
    puts "You have pressed #{key}"
end
```

If you type 'f', it works fine, but if you type 'g' per example, there are 2 problems :

- The "case when" runs all cases, not only for 'g' char
- The STDIN.getc in the WHILE loop seems to be executed 2 times, even if I type only one time a char.

Where is the mistake ?

Answer (score 1):

Do not know exactly but it seems like `STDIN.getc` does not block loop.
You can try something like this

```
puts "Press a key"
while key = gets.chomp
  break if key == "f"
  puts key.class
  puts "You have pressed #{key}"
  puts key.class

  case key
  when "g"
    puts "It's 'g'"
  when "h"
    puts "It's 'h'"
  when "j"
    puts "It's 'j'"
  else
    puts "You gave me #{key} -- I have no idea what to do with that."
  end

  puts "Press a key"
end
```